# Use more ram on laptop with a trick

Tags: memory, ramdisk

Hi I have this laptop which is perfect and has 16 gb of ram, but some programs go crazy and I run outta ram.

So not that perfect!

I have another laptop which has 8gb of ram.

What I'm trying to achieve could not work,and could be also stupid.That's why I'm asking here by the way.

Now I want to use that 8gb ram as much as possible somehow.

So my way would be,turn the ram into a ram disk on the second laptop,share it through network with the first laptop.

Is it practical?
A Lan cable could be the best option here?

What's better than this if it's practical?And what to do instead if it isn't practical.

Please don't suggest using ssd, I have an ssd on my first laptop already.I will never use it as a ram backup.
Ssd's are not still ready for that,they're too fragile.

Comment: SSDs are perfectly suited for RAM backup duties so long as precautions are taken, in fact their performance characteristics make them far better than hard disk: https://superuser.com/questions/262635/using-a-ssd-as-my-only-drive-on-a-laptop/262640#262640 So long as you have enough spare capacity for the wear leveller to do it's job and the system is not essentially operating *entirely* from the SSD then they are a perfectly good to use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I know ssd are better than hdds for doing this, but my question was using a ramdisk not hdd, and thanks for the information. Unfortunately my os and all programs are on ssd so I can't do this as you described.

Comment: You might be able to create a ramdisk and put swap on it, but you will be constrained by the speed of your network connection - likely less then 125megabyte/sec + ?? .2ms ?? latency - so not great but better then hdd. You have not stipulated an OS, but under Linux the solution would be to add swap and set VM.swappiness to about 5 to assist the OS in memory management. Not

Comment: Yes exactly the network could be the only problem, can't I use something faster to connect my laptops?125 megabytes/second is that when using Lan cable?and which kind? My os is macos